# Python float() error with 0.4893-6 numbers

Tags: python

Is it possible to change a string to float with numbers formatted without E?

I get an error trying `float("0.333-5")`. Float numbers in Python are with an `e` or `E`. 
Any idea? How can add the E easily?

Comment: probably find all occurrences of `+` and `-` and replace them with an additional `e`.

Comment: How are large numbers formatted? 5E7 => 5+7?

Comment: `float("2.3e+7")` with small or capital `E`.

Comment: have you tried regular expressions or replacing the - with something, as @Alex said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub('(.)([-+]\d)', r'\1e\2', number_string)
```

where `number_string = 0.333-5`. This will work for negative numbers and also for a format like `.5-5`.

Comment: Good, but it does not work with 1.-5… Replacing the leading `(\d)` with `(.)` would work. Also, there is no need to use a raw string in the first regexp, and you can directly use `[-+]` instead of using escapes…

Answer (score 0):

just replace the minus sign with a minus preceded by the e

```
s = "0.333-5"
s = s.replace('-','e-')
float(s)
```

If you can have even plus signs, you will have to do a double replacement

```
s.replace('-','e-').replace('+','e+')
```

Comment: you can first split by '.' then replace minus on the second value and join them back.